# How can I achieve this light blue effect behind the text in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, web

How can I achieve this light blue effect behind the text in HTML & CSS? .

[Here's the image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNpbW.png)

Comment: show your HTML CSS code... what you have done

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: I don't know how to do that.. that's why I am asking for help. Isn't this the place to ask these questions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could be done:

```css
.effect {
  color: #0e0e33;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* the effect itself: */

.effect:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #bcf8fd;
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}


/*EDIT: you also need a container for it not to fall apart*/

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="effect">Art &amp; NFTs.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man Thank you soo much for this. I was really struggling with it.